# Redis cache error in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, redis

I want to install Redis cache in my magento website so first I need to install Redis cache in my server and after that need to add some code in my Magento app/etc/local.xml file that I know but I am getting error that **`Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.`**

Below is my process to install redis cache in server and website so if there is any mistake help me to solve this.

May I need to install **PhpRedis extension** ? and how and where to install it?in server or website? Also I thing I need to add cronjob so where can I add cronjob? in magento root directory's cron.php file?

first of all I connect my server using **putty** and go to root directory of website and after that I run below command that I find from **http://redis.io/download**

**`$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.0.tar.gz`**

**`$ tar xzf redis-3.2.0.tar.gz`**

**`$ cd redis-3.2.0`**

**$ make**

**`$ src/redis-server`**

after doing this I go to **magento_root/app/etc/local.xml** and place below code in **`<globle>`** tag.

```
<cache>
      <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
      <backend_options>
        <server>redis11.i</server>
        <port>6379</port>
        <persistent></persistent>
        <database>0</database>
        <password></password>
        <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
        <connect_retries>3</connect_retries>
        <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
        <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
        <compress_data>1</compress_data>
        <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
        <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
        <compression_lib>lzf</compression_lib>
      </backend_options>
    </cache>

    <session_save>db</session_save>
    <redis_session>             
        <host>redis1.i</host>  
        <port>6379</port>
        <timeout>2.5</timeout>  
        <persistent></persistent>
        <db>0</db>
        <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold> 
        <compression_lib>lzf</compression_lib> 
        <log_level>4</log_level>
        <log_broken_locks>0</log_broken_locks>            
        <max_concurrency>10</max_concurrency>
        <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
        <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>            
        <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime> 
        <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
        <bot_lifetime>3600</bot_lifetime>
        <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>
        <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>
        <max_lifetime>86400</max_lifetime>
    </redis_session>
```

I think I have mistaken somewhere in **local.xml** file to put correct value for all tags so please look at all tags and if anyone knows please help.

**UPDATE**

Most of the thing in local.xml file I copy from internet and past to my file so I don't know some of the tags for what? so subsequently don't know that what is the correct value for these tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hate just posting a link, but these instructions have never seen me wrong

http://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/

### edit, just to expand.

is redis installed locally?
here is one of my local.xmls' i just use 127.0.0.1

```
<cache>
          <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>              <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>               <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
          </backend_options>
        </cache>
<full_page_cache>
          <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>              <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>               <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>1</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
          </backend_options>
```

Comment: I refer this link but not understand all point because I am newbie to magento and redis.

Comment: May I copy and paste this code to my local.xml file or need to change anything like persistent , database etc.

Comment: And how to check that redis is install in server or not?

Comment: May I need to install **PhpRedis extension**?

Comment: from cli type:   redis-cli    :: if that returns a different prompt (mine looks liek 127.0.0.1/>  )  the monitor command will output what redis is caching

Comment: above code I can run from magento root directory?

Comment: anywhere if redis is installed correctly, the magento config part, just details how Mage interacts wiht redis.

Comment: from magento root I run **cli type: redis-cli** command and it's show me error that **cli:command not found**

Comment: sorry, just redis-cli from the command prompt then enter

Comment: did you succeed? if so please mark as answered so other could benifit.